# How to mount my Galaxy Nexus storage under Debian?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, internal-storage, mount

I can't copy anything to my Galaxy Nexus right now. I've installed `mtpfs 0.9-3` and tried to mount the storage of my Galaxy Nexus with `mtpfs -o allow_other /media/phone`. When I try to change to the mount point now, the whole terminal instance hangs, unless I kill `mtpfs`.

Sometimes I get `cannot access phone: Software caused connection abort`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you seen the question [How do I mount a Kindle Fire 10.2.6 on my Linux computer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38304/how-do-i-mount-a-kindle-fire-10-2-6-on-my-linux-computer/39502#39502). The answer to that question has shown how to successfully mount a Nexus on a Linux, which I presume a shot worth to try.