# Although I have enough the available storage does not match it

Tags: insufficient-memory

On a Samsung note 10.1 with 32G when I go to settings I can see 25GB available storage. Besides that, when I am trying to copy files from my ubuntu box to the tablet (connected through the USB) I am getting an insufficient storage message. Checking the properties of the mounted volume I only see 200MB free on it.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I just answered the first part of your question below. For the remaining part, a few more details are needed: Can you please check which partition is mounted there? You might be able to identify some files/directories, compare them with your device using a file manager or terminal, and then give the full path. I'm suspecting it mounts the wrong partition. Also please specify how you mount your Note (MTP, UMS, PTP).

Comment: It is mounted automatically. When I connect the tablet (Sumsung note) to the USB of the computer, a pop is notifying me that I have inserted a digital audion player.  I can see it from nautilous. The directory mounted is the /storage/sdcard0  which has not the same free space as what is shown in the android settings | strorage | free

Comment: OK, "digital audio player" suggests it's using PTP or MTP, but certainly not UMS (the latter would be "USB Storage", not "Audio Player" or "Camera"). Do you have the `mtp-tools` package installed on your Ubuntu PC? My [answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39502/16575) might prove helpful (ignore the Kindle, focus on the Ubuntu part ;)

Comment: After installing mtpfs and creating the dir ~/NexusDrive I am executing: mtpfs ~/NexusDrive, it finds the devide but it gets stuck showing the messgae:  Attempting to connect device.  All this is happening while the tablet is connected through the usb. Do I miss something here?

Comment: Sorry, John: As I don't use it myself, I cannot further check. I recommend you post a new question with this issue: include the steps you've performed, including the error message. Hopefully somebody using this can help you further. It might also be a good idea to not post this question here, but on our sister-site [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), as it's the Ubuntu-part it is about. I hope I at least was able to answer the first part of your question below (so you might accept it), and got you started in the right direction with the other part.

Comment: ok, i accepted and will start a new thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with 32 GB when I go to settings I can see 25 GB available storage

Though the device is declared to have 32GB, part of that is reserved for the firmware. The entire 32GB are partitioned:

- `/system` for the [device-firmware](/questions/tagged/device-firmware)
- `/recovery` for the recovery (see: [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode))
- `/boot` for the boot image
- `/cache` for application cache
- `/data` for apps and their data (see: [internal-storage](/questions/tagged/internal-storage))

The 25 GB you see are those from the [internal-storage](/questions/tagged/internal-storage) aka `/data`.

<sup>This answer only covers the first part of your question. For the second part, we need some more details.</sup>