# How to connect Sony Xperia L with Ubuntu?

Tags: connection-issues, linux, sony-xperia-l

How do I connect my Sony Xperia L in MTP mode with Ubuntu? If I connect in MTP mode, Ubuntu fails to read my files from internal storage.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

That might depend on which Android version your device it running. Some devices additional support [USB mass storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass_storage_device_class). Also: there are some packages you might install/update on your Ubuntu side, to support mtpfs (see e.g. answers [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/52308/16575) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/39502/16575)).

Alternatively, you might wish to go the "ADB way" (this is how I do it on my Ubuntu box). Here you would need a basic ADB installation (see: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)) and `adbfs` (see [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/58783/16575)). In both cases, you can use graphical file managers as well as the command line to deal with your files.

Answer (score 0):

Normally mass storage mode was not supported by Sony xperia L if it doesn't had any sdcard.So,you have to connect the xperia L with Ubuntu in MTP mode to see its content.

In Ubuntu,an android device which was connected in MTP mode was not detected if it was pluggedin to any one of the USB 2.0 ports.For getting your device detected in Ubuntu,you have to plugin the phone in USB 3.0 port.

Port with black tongue - USB 2.0 port

Port with blue tongue - USB 3.0 port

Tested in Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10.