# What file system for Asus Zenfone 2 on CentOS 6.9?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, file-system, file-permissions

I'm trying to mount my Android Asus Zenfone 2 on CentOS 6.9. I created a folder in `/mnt/android` as the mounting point. I edited the `/etc/fstab` file in the following way because somewhere in some forums I read that *jmtp*  file system correctly handles the Android phones' file system. But now the OS doesn't automatically read the file-system of my phone when I connect it via USB to my PC. Can you help me figure out what file system I could use in the `/etc/fstab` in order for me to access files correctly?
Thank you.

```
[dolly@centos mnt]$ sudo cp android/"Internal storage"/WhatsApp/* ~/Pictures/
[sudo] password for dolly: 
cp: cannot stat `android/Internal storage/WhatsApp/*': No such file or directory
[dolly@centos mnt]$ sudo cp android/'Internal storage'/WhatsApp/* ~/Pictures/
cp: cannot stat `android/Internal storage/WhatsApp/*': No such file or directory
[dolly@centos mnt]$
```

**/etc/fstab/ file**

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Fri Oct 27 00:03:17 2017
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/vg_hpdv6000-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=8b4c9d1b-6bcb-4bfc-b48f-146a415fb8f3 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_hpdv6000-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/sda1           /mnt/win ntfs-3g rw,umask=0000,defaults 0 0
jmtpfs                  /mnt/android fuse nodev,allow_other,rw,user,noauto,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

===

## EDIT 1

I've got Andoroid 5.0 Lollipop. I had chosen it among the tags for this question but I can understand if someone missed it.

The filesystem I'm looking for is one that allows me to copy some old classical music, from the PC into the phone. I have Fuse package installed and it allows me to read/write files from my Windows 7 partition.

Comment: Isn't that rather a question for Linux&Unix.SE? On Android we usually don't edit fstab files – and I just wonder why your corresponding fstab entry starts with a file system instead of the device. So I wonder how the device should be identified there at all. But as said, that's rather not an Android question but a CentOS/Linux one.

Comment: @Izzy We have many other questions about accessing the phone via MTP from a Linux desktop, e.g. [this one about mtpfs on Ubuntu](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/52072/12442). I think this one is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @DanHulme which is why I didn't VTC. Though, as I've pointed out, it IMHO weights more on Linux specifics. OP didn't mention the Android version used; I e.g. use [`adbfs`](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless) to access my Android devices, which works fine at least up to Android 6.